# Index of pointer to a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to find out, why the output of the following program is "WAHNAHNN".

My question is: 
Why does the index i rise above p[4] (i.e. exceed the length of the array) and why does it produce another "AHNN" after the "WAHN"?

I am still confused with the difference between p+i (which should be a location) and *(p+i) which should be a value. Why is the output a value in both cases?

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
     char a[] = "WAHN";
     char *p = a;
     for (int i=0; p[i]; i=i+1)
         switch (i%2) {
             case 0: cout << p+i;
             break;
             case 1: cout << *(p+i);
             break;
         }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: The reason is that the `operator <<` on `ostream` is overloaded for `char *` [as you can see in the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/)

Comment: It is difficult to understand what is your confusion. i=0 print the string "WAHN", i=1 print the character "A", i=2 print the string "HN", i=3 print the character "N", then it's what's you code.

Comment: @mpromonet Please do not add C tags to questions that contain C++ code.

Answer (score 4):

The type of `p + i` is `char*`.

The `operator <<` interprets this as a nullterminated string. This means that the program will output "WHAN" (`i == 0` so `p + i == p`, wich is the same as `a`) for the first iteration, "A" for the second iteration, "HN" for the third and "N" for the last one.